# Can I write a lighttpd plugin for windows?

Tags: windows, plugins, lighttpd

I would like to write a [lighttpd](http://www.lighttpd.net/) plugin, as explained [here](http://www.lighttpd.net/). I use lighty for Windows, with the pre-compiled package from [here](http://en.wlmp-project.net/downloads.php?cat=lighty).

It appears that to make a plugin, I need to modify source code and recompile lightly. Problem is, the Windows project doesn't contain source code to build for windows. It only contains the final binaries.

Is there a solution here? Or do I need to "re-invent the wheel" and get the original lighty source compiling on Windows myself, if I want to be able to make a plugin for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
For making a lighttpd plugin in Windows, 
You have to get a source and then compile through cygwin or mingw.
Because @WLMP only service lighttpd binary file with other modules for windows.
```

1. [Lighttpd 1.5 with mingw](https://github.com/mkottman/lighttpd-1.5-mingw)
   : Need svn (dowloading source), MinGW, CMake, FastCgi, OpenSSL.
2. [Cygwin Lighttpd with SSL](http://blog.dt.org/index.php/2009/03/cygwin-lighttpd-with-ssl/)
   : A little old contents related with lighttpd v1.4.20 and Cygwin.

```
Unfortunately there is no VC build environment for lighttpd lately.
But based on reference 1&2, You can build your own lighttpd plugin.
```